# Typeclass conversion in Haskell

Tags: class, haskell, types, type-conversion, typeclass

I have this assignment where I am unsure where to start. So one of the things is to do a
maybe to either conversion with this signature:

> maybeEither:: Maybe a -> Either () a

and the other is of course the opposite

> eitherMaybe:: Either () a -> Maybe a

so when you call one of the other they will cancel eachother out.
Now I don't really know where to begin here... Can someone help?

Extra question: How would I convert a function for example `(Int->a) -> a` and `a -> (Int->a)`
Like since in the second example you really can't give the function as a parameter to the function that converts, Im not sure how that would go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, these are not typeclasses, they're data types.  If you're unfamiliar with the difference, I would recommend reading the relevant chapters in Learn You a Haskell.

---

To solve this particular problem, you just need to pattern match on the different constructors:

```
maybeEither :: Maybe a -> Either () a
maybeEither Nothing = ???
maybeEither (Just a) = ???
```

And

```
eitherMaybe :: Either () a -> Maybe a
eitherMaybe (Left x) = ???
eitherMaybe (Right y) = ???
```

You just need to fill in the the `???`s and you're done.

---

For your extra question, remember that the signature `a -> (Int -> a)` is the same as `a -> Int -> a`, since `->` is right associative.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's very simple, just follow the types to see what you get. The type signature of `maybeEither` suggests that it takes `Maybe a` as input.

`Maybe` is defined like this:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

Also, from the type sigature, you can get that `maybeEither` gives `Either () a` as the output for the function.

`Either` type constructor is defined like this:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

Now, replace `a` with `()` and you will get:

`Either () b = Left () | Right b`

Or you can replace your type variables to make it clear,

```
Either () a = Left () | Right a
```

Now, the implementation of the function is pretty straightforward.

```
maybeEither :: Maybe a -> Either () a
maybeEither (Just x) = ??? -- fill these
maybeEither Nothing = ???
```

You can follow the same approach for your other function.

Comment: May I suggest you remove the `data` keyword from versions where you substitute in for the type variable?

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks, but can I know why ? `()` is just another type having `()` as a value.

Comment: I don't think it's valid Haskell! A `data` declaration has one type constructor and perhaps several type variables. `()` is a type constructor, not a type variable. You can write the equation `Either () a = Left () | Right a`, but I don't think there's any way to express that *directly* in Haskell, so it's best not to pretend you are.